# Semaphores and concurrent programming

Tags: c, concurrency, semaphore

For a homework assignment i need to program the following scenario. This is going to be done using semaphores using BACI (which is C--)

There are 2 unisex restrooms that can hold 4 people each. Since it is unisex only people of the same sex can be in the restroom at the same time and FIFO is not important.  I have the basic "algorithm" in my head to handle 4 men and 4 woman for 1 restroom.  But i don't know how to code this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is what I have.

```
Woman:

Check to see if there are any men in the restroom. If so "wait".
If no men check to see if there are 4 people. If so "wait".
If no men and not 4 use restroom. When leaving signal there is a vacancy.
If last woman signal the men if they are waiting if not signal the woman.


Man:

check to see if there are any woman in the restroom. if so "wait"
If no woman check to see if there are 4 people. If so "wait".
If no woman and not 4 use restroom. when leaving signal there is a vacancy.
if last man signal the women if they are waiting if not signal the men.
```

These additional instructions were provided

- Use random FOR loops to simulate the passage of time in the appropriate places. This can be easily done by using a Delay function:

  ```
  void Delay (void)
  { 
    int i;
    int DelayTime;
    DelayTime = random (DELAY);
    for (i = 0; i < DelayTime; i++):
  }
  ```
- where const int DELAY = some number from 10 to 100.
- Print and format output nicely and print messages in such a way that by reading the output, one can trace the execution order.
- Set the processes up to loop forever, and use control C (or control break) to stop your program.

Comment: No. But it can't have starvation.  So men and women have to use the restroom fairly.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're worried about starvation, but I'm pretty sure your algorithm has a starvation problem. Imagine the case where one man shows up while a woman is already in the bathroom, and a steady stream of women keep showing up so that the bathroom never empties.

Comment: yes. this is one of the issues i'm seeing and i'm needing help with. The starvation.  could this be fixed by having each woman signal a man and each man signal a woman?

Comment: How about limiting it so that any time you reach 4 people in the queue of the other gender you switch genders. That way your starvation problem is fixed.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  My question now is how do I set up the Woman and man process so that 4 people can go in the restroom at a time? I've got my program running so that it allows 1 person in the restroom at a time without deadlock or starvation. but there can be 4 people in the restroom at a time.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but your delay function is broken. Any good compiler will compile it to the equivalent of: `void Delay(void) { random(DELAY); }`

Comment: How are you handling transgender bathroom occupants?

Comment: @WoLpH I don't think that will fix the starvation problem. If you have only one man show up while the restroom is being occupied by a woman, he is still left crossing his legs indefinetly.  I think starvation needs to be addressed by considering both bathrooms.  I.E, if the queue contains both genders, one restroom services men, the other women, with appropriate signalling to allow both to service the same gender when there are none of the other gender in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to know `how to code your algorithm for 1 restroom`, I have done so in C. It will be a fairly simple task to convert it into C--, as all the semaphore constructs appear quite similar.

From what I could make of your answer,

```
C: sem_wait()  C--: wait()
   sem_post()       signal()
   sem_t            semaphore()
   sem_init()       initialsem()
```

Bear in mind, as stated, I have worked out the problem for **1-restroom** only. Since this is homework, I expect you to expand it into the **2-restrooms** form yourself.

Working one's way from the [Readers-writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem) to our "Unisex Restroom" problem, we make use of the following global variables:

```
int mcount,wcount; // count of number of men/women in restroom
sem_t x,y,z;       // semaphores for updating mcount & wcount values safely
sem_t wsem,msem;   // semaphores to block other genders' entry  
sem_t cap;         // capacity of the restroom
```

Incorporating these semaphores & counters into the `man` thread function,

```
void *man(void *param)
{           
    sem_wait(&z);                
        sem_wait(&msem);        
            sem_wait(&x);
                mcount++;
                if(mcount==1)   
                { sem_wait(&wsem); } // first man in, make women wait
            sem_post(&x);
        sem_post(&msem);
    sem_post(&z);

    sem_wait(&cap);  //wait here, if over capacity

    printf("\t\tman in!\n");
    delay();
    printf("\t\t\tman out!\n");

    sem_post(&cap);  //one man has left, increase capacity

    sem_wait(&x);
        mcount--;
        if(mcount==0)
        {sem_post(&wsem);}  // no man left, signal women 
    sem_post(&x);
}
```

Similarly, the woman thread function, substitutes `mcount` with `wcount`, `msem` with `wsem`, and `x` with `y`. Only `z` remains as is in the `man` function, so that both `man` & `woman` threads queue up on the same common semaphore. (Due to this, the code invariably has **FIFO-like** behaviour, which ensures **fairness/non-starvation**)

The complete code is as follows: (To compile, use `gcc filename -lpthread`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int mcount,wcount;
sem_t x,y,z,wsem,msem,cap;

void delay(void)
{
    int i;
    int delaytime;
    delaytime = random();
    for (i = 0; i<delaytime; i++);
}

void *woman(void *param)
{
    sem_wait(&z);
        sem_wait(&wsem);
            sem_wait(&y);
                wcount++;
                if(wcount==1)
                { sem_wait(&msem); }
            sem_post(&y);
        sem_post(&wsem);
    sem_post(&z);

    sem_wait(&cap);

    printf("woman in!\n");
    delay();
    printf("\twoman out!\n");

    sem_post(&cap);     

    sem_wait(&y);
        wcount--;
        if(wcount==0)
        { sem_post(&msem); }
    sem_post(&y);
}

void *man(void *param)
{           
    sem_wait(&z);
        sem_wait(&msem);
            sem_wait(&x);
                mcount++;
                if(mcount==1)
                { sem_wait(&wsem); }
            sem_post(&x);
        sem_post(&msem);
    sem_post(&z);

    sem_wait(&cap);

    printf("\t\tman in!\n");
    delay();
    printf("\t\t\tman out!\n");

    sem_post(&cap);

    sem_wait(&x);
        mcount--;
        if(mcount==0)
        {sem_post(&wsem);}
    sem_post(&x);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    srandom(60);

        mcount = 0;
        wcount = 0;
        sem_init(&x,0,1);  // for sem_init, initial value is 3rd argument
        sem_init(&y,0,1);
        sem_init(&z,0,1);
        sem_init(&wsem,0,1);
        sem_init(&msem,0,1);
        sem_init(&cap,0,4);  // eg. cap initialized to 4

        pthread_t *tid;
        tid = malloc(80*sizeof(pthread_t));

    // You can use your cobegin statement here, instead of pthread_create()     
    // I have forgone the use of pthread barriers although I suppose they would nicely imitate the functionality of cobegin. 
    // This is merely to retain simplicity.

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,woman,NULL);
    }
    for(i=10;i<20;i++)
    {     
            pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,man,NULL);
    }
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {     
            pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

While converting into the **2-restrooms** form, make note of which semaphores & counter variables you would need to duplicate to satisfy all the conditions. Happy *semaphoring*!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have.  This allows 1 person in the restroom at a time without deadlock or starvation.  I'm in need of assistance with how to make it so 4 people can be in the restroom at a time.

```
const int Delayx = 60;
int i;
semaphore max_capacity;
semaphore woman;
semaphore man;
semaphore mutex;

void Delay(void)
{
    int DelayTime;
    DelayTime = random(Delayx);
    for (i = 0; i<DelayTime; i++);
}

void Woman(void)
{
    wait(woman);
    wait(max_capacity);
    wait(mutex);
    cout << "A Woman has entered Restroom"<<endl;
    Delay();
    cout << "A woman has exited Restroom"<<endl;
    signal(mutex);
    signal(max_capacity);
    signal(man);
}

void Man(void)
{
    wait(man);
    wait(max_capacity);
    wait(mutex);
    cout <<"A Man has entered the Restroom"<<endl;
    Delay();
    cout << "A man has exited the Restroom"<<endl;
    signal(mutex);
    signal(max_capacity);
    signal(woman);
}

void main()
{
    initialsem(woman,1);
    initialsem(man,1);
    initialsem(max_capacity,4);
    initialsem(mutex,1);
    cobegin
    {
        Woman(); Woman(); Woman(); Woman(); Woman(); Woman(); Woman(); Woman(); Man();  Man(); Man(); Man(); Man(); Man(); Man(); Man();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for 4 restroom baci code :

```
 const int Delayx = 60;
   int i;
   int Mcount,Wcount;
   binarysem x,y,z,Wsem,Msem;
   semaphore cap;
   void Delay(void)
   {
    int DelayTime;
    DelayTime = random(Delayx);
    for (i = 0; i<DelayTime; i++);
     }

 void Woman(void)
   {
     wait(z);
     wait(Wsem);
     wait(y);
     Wcount++;
     if(Wcount==1)
       { wait(Msem);  }
       signal(y);
       signal(Wsem);
       signal(z);

       wait(cap);
       cout << "A Woman has entered Restroom"<<endl;
       Delay();
       cout << "A Woman has exited Restroom"<<endl;

       signal(cap);
       wait(y);
       Wcount--;
       if(Wcount==0)
         {signal(Msem);}

        signal(y);
        }

 void Man(void)
  {
     wait(z);
     wait(Msem);
     wait(x);
     Mcount++;
     if(Mcount==1)
       { wait(Wsem);  }
       signal(x);
       signal(Msem);
       signal(z);

       wait(cap);
       cout << "A Man has entered Restroom"<<endl;
       Delay();
       cout << "A Man has exited Restroom"<<endl;

       signal(cap);
       wait(x);
       Mcount--;
       if(Mcount==0)
         {signal(Wsem);}

        signal(x);
        }


void main()
{
Mcount=0;
Wcount=0;
initialsem(x,1);
initialsem(y,1);
initialsem(z,1);
initialsem(Wsem,1);
initialsem(Msem,1);
initialsem(cap,4);
cobegin
{
    Woman(); Woman(); Woman();
    Woman(); Woman(); Woman(); 
    Woman();
    Woman(); Man();  Man();
    Man(); Man(); Man(); Man();
    Man(); Man();
}
      }
```